# re-write all links on page to open in new tab through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To make all links in a page non-clickable, I use the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.body.onclick=function(e){
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.ebay.com">Link 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I know that to make a link open in a new tab we can use:

```
target="_blank"
```

But that is not the question here, the question is, how can I:

1) Make all links clickable through javascript after first making them non-clickable as shown above.

2) Use javascript to re-write all the URLs in the page to open in a new tab, AKA how can I use javascript to add the necessary `target="_blank"` attribute to all links in any HTML page?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.body.onclick=function(e){ // or addEventListener
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
window.onload=function() {
  document.body.onclick=null;
  var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].target="_blank";
  }
}
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://www.ebay.com">Link 2</a>
</body>
</html
```

or in jQuery use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("body").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false; // not necessary
});
$(function() {
  $("body").off("click");
  $("a").attr("target")="_blank";
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you could enable clicks on links, you could change the default target by adding this tag to the page `<head>`:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set each anchor's `target` property  to `'_blank'`

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => a.target = '_blank' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy like this:

```
var aList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0 ; i < aList.length; i++){
    aList[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

But you need to put it at the end of the document.

But if you don't like it to be at the end of the document and also want it to work across all browsers you can do something like this:

```
var DOMReady = function(a,b,c){b=document,c='addEventListener';b[c]?b[c]('DOMContentLoaded',a):window.attachEvent('onload',a)}

DOMReady(function () {
  var aList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0 ; i < aList.length; i++){
    aList[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
});
```

The DOMReady function is for when the document structure was shaped in the dom. This part was used from another code in this page: [Tiny Cross Browser DOM Ready](https://gist.github.com/dciccale/4087856)

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

instead of

```
document.body.onclick=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

BUT, keep in mind that you need to include jQuery to be able to do so.